# Sink in Flink blocks the task execution

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a Sink in Flink, which extends from RichSinkFunction.
It delays the execution of all the Flink task (if I remove it, it takes a half, from 10' to less than 5'). This is its configuration:

```
OutputTag<List<SessionSinkModel>> inProgressSessionOutputTag = new OutputTag<>(ProcessorConstants.IN_PROGRESS_SESSIONS_SINK_NAME) {};           
    
SingleOutputStreamOperator<SessionAccumulator> aggregatedSessionStream =
    collectionMessageDataStream
        .keyBy(CollectionMessage::getSessionId)
        .process(sessionKeyedProcessFunction)
        .uid("SessionWindow")
        .name("Session Window")
        .setParallelism(4);
            
DataStream<List<SessionSinkModel>> inProgressSessionStream =  aggregatedSessionStream
                            .getSideOutput(inProgressSessionOutputTag);
                
inProgressSessionStream
    .broadcast()
    .addSink(new SessionAPISink(config))
    .uid("Sessions side output")
    .name("Sessions side output");
```

This Sink sends massive data by POST to an endpoint, this POST call is asynchronous (as far as I know like the Sink call). I use the standard call using the output from *KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction.ReadOnlyContext* **ctx**.

```
ctx.output(outputTag, message);
```

How can I do to make this Sink not to block the task execution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that I see with the workflow...

1. You shouldn't be doing a `inProgressSessionStream.broadcast()`
2. For efficient async IO, you want to use Flink's [AsyncIO support](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/), and then follow that with a DiscardingSink.

Comment: Anyway I need all the data in the sinks. I have a timeout to allow the sinks to finish, i suppose that if I discard the sink I will lose the data.

Comment: The `DiscardingSink` is there to terminate the workflow pipe. The data is sent by the preceding Async IO operator. Please take a look at the link to AsyncIO support.